# Type erasure with generics specialized type

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors, covariance, type-erasure

I'm trying to understand the java compiler generics types erasure with the following exemple. Can someone explain me why can i add a new motor bike into a list of Car ?

```
List<Vehicle> list = (List<Vehicle>)(Object)new ArrayList<Car>(); 
list.add(new MotorBike());
```

Comment: Firstly we dont know your class structure. Secondly: *"can"* referring to runtime or compile time - have you tried retrieving the object back from the list?

Comment: The answer is in the question: type erasure. Google that term, and you'll have plenty of answers.

Comment: @luk2302 You can always do `((List)list).get(0)`.

Comment: @luk2302 i had not describe my class structure because it is obvious. Car and MotorBike inherit from vehicle. 
Yes i've tried this ! it works. 
I understand why comilation succeed i just don't know why runtime accept my add

Comment: Because Runtime does not have generics and List contains Objects